# Nativemodule AsyncStorage is null after pod install

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I get this error in my emulator after I install the pod on my ejected app:

```
pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
```

I have restarted my build process, but still get the error. Any ideas?

```
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
"react": "16.8.5",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
```

After I install:

[image]

I also get alot of warnings:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing RNCAsyncStorage (1.6.1)
Installing RNShare (1.2.1)
Installing React (0.11.0)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
npm install --production

npm WARN deprecated connect@2.8.3: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated babel-core@5.8.21: Babel 5 is no longer being maintained. Upgrade to Babel 6.
npm WARN deprecated joi@5.1.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.3.22: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated line-numbers@0.2.0: Copy its ~20 LOC directly into your code instead.
npm WARN deprecated topo@1.1.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.6.3: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@1.2.0: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@0.0.3: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.1.1: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead
npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.1.2: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.1.3: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/facebook/react.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookpro2018/.npm/_logs/2019-08-28T13_00_14_293Z-debug.log


[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `9.0` on target `tcapp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `tvos` with version `9.2` on target `tcapp-tvOS` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Comment: did you try to link asyncstorage ?

Comment: Yes it says already linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install` again.

Comment: But not for IOS build?

Comment: No not working on iOS, works on Android, I do get lots of warnings in the terminal on IOS. Any ideas?

Comment: I remember linking is a bit buggy for IOS. I would try it manually. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

Comment: I can only see the ios folder in xcode, I cant drag files from node_modules above it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever bundled for IOS? My attempt would be: create a new project, try building it. Then you know if it's really a problem with the async storage or if there is a general problem.